Migration to AuthorizationClient API
In the Google Play console, I found a notification that the Google Sign-in API will soon stop working and I need to switch to the AuthorizationClient API. There are almost no instructions for migration, I only found this example https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization/android
The code written there works fine, but I don’t understand how to log out of the account (to sign in to another account).
When I first call the code from the example, I get a dialog for choosing an account. But after successful authorization - it can no longer be seen after re-executing the code. Previously, I called the GoogleSignInClient.signOut() method for this purpose, but in the new class (AuthorizationClient) there is nothing similar
